# How to import this JavaScript library?

Tags: typescript, npm

I downloaded `easystar.js` with npm.

Its code looks like this:

```js
export const TOP: 'TOP'
export const TOP_RIGHT: 'TOP_RIGHT'
export const RIGHT: 'RIGHT'
export const BOTTOM_RIGHT: 'BOTTOM_RIGHT'
export const BOTTOM: 'BOTTOM'
export const BOTTOM_LEFT: 'BOTTOM_LEFT'
export const LEFT: 'LEFT'
export const TOP_LEFT: 'TOP_LEFT'

type Direction = 'TOP' | 'TOP_RIGHT' | 'RIGHT' | 'BOTTOM_RIGHT' | 'BOTTOM' | 'BOTTOM_LEFT' | 'LEFT' | 'TOP_LEFT'

export class js {

  /**
   * Sets the collision grid that EasyStar uses.
   *
   * @param {Array|Number} tiles An array of numbers that represent
   * which tiles in your grid should be considered
   * acceptable, or "walkable".
   */
  setAcceptableTiles(tiles: number[] | number): void

.
.
.
  removeAllDirectionalConditions(): void
}
```

I've tried importing in all these ways:

```js
import * as easystar from 'easystarjs';
import 'easystarjs';
import {js} from 'easystarjs';
```

but I can't see anything called easystar or js in my window object if I put a breakpoint there.  What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: That code looks an awful lot like TypeScript, not JavaScript

Comment: What is the actual name of the library? `easystar`, `easystar.js`, `easystarjs`, or something else?

Comment: Are you using this imports in node js ?

Comment: Are you using any framework in which you use this npm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this way to import it in your js.

If you are using `node js` :

```
var easystarjs = require('easystarjs');
var easystar = new easystarjs.js();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! How did you know it needs to use `require`, not `import`? I can't tell the difference.

Comment: Node js default uses import method using require() function.
If you want to use import instead of require() then you should integrate babel with node js and compile node'd code ecmascript supportable.

Comment: I'm using `Parcel.js`. All my other npm packages work fine with `import`, but not this one :(

Comment: This is because this npm package might not exported in ES module format.

Answer (score 1):

if you making `"type": "module"` inside nodejs then this is working:

```js
import easystarjs from 'easystarjs'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm 99.99% sure, this code is TypeScript, not JavaScript. Pure TypeScript code won't work in browsers, it has to be compiled to pure JavaScript prior to that. If you open Dev Tools, you'll probably see some `SyntaxError`s.

Then, there's the name of the library and the file, – you are being pretty ambiguous on that. Both `easystar`, `easystar.js`, as well as `easystarjs` could be three separate libraries, completely independent from each other.

Lastly (assuming all the above issues are fixed), importing an entity doesn't mean putting it at `window` object, – you still have to explicitly say `window.something = something`.